# Google-sheets – Conditional Format if cell in one column contains partial match from another column

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to find a custom formula to highlight a cell from one column (A) if it contains a partial text from another column (C)

I created a sample spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10m3lHi45BFtKuvDKUbOFAkxjAOhr0VtAnWASwgFIVGY/edit?usp=sharing

What I tried so far is this
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("*"&INDIRECT("$A1")&"*",$C1,0)>0,true,),false)

but that only works with the first cell
also tried REGEXMATCH and search but couldn't come up with the right formula

Comment: Hi. File is shared as View Only

Comment: It's now editable, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try with this, it joins the whole C column and matches with REGEXMATCH. The second parenthesis excludes when the cell is empty:

```
=REGEXMATCH(JOIN(",",C:C),A1)*(A1<>"")
```

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(A1,TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,$C:$C),1)),)*(A1<>""))
```

[image]